# Why does not java.net.URI parse authority part?

Tags: java, parsing, uri

Why does the following code print `Illegal character in scheme name at index 0: 8.8.8.8:80` ?

```java
try {
  URI uri = new URI("8.8.8.8:80");
  System.out.println(uri.getAuthority());
} catch(Exception e){
  System.out.println(e.getMessage());
}
```

Are numeric addresses accepted? On [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Identifier), examples list `telnet://192.0.2.16:80/` as a valid URI example. Also, [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URI.html)  for URI class says that scheme is optional.

> At the highest level a URI reference (hereinafter simply "URI") in string form has the syntax
>
> `[scheme:]scheme-specific-part[#fragment]`

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, `scheme-specific-part` includes `//` and so without it parsing fails. When string is defined as "//8.8.8.8:80" output is, as expected, "8.8.8.8:80"